# Use generic home directory reference from launch file

Tags: roslaunch, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running a .bag file from a launch file but I want to make the filepath generic so other team members can run this launch file. So I have:

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="player" args="/home/jimbob/bagfiles/test.bag" />
</launch>
```

But not everyone on my team is named jimbob so I want to replace "/home/jimbob/" with maybe ${HOME} or something generic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219598/use-generic-home-directory-reference-from-launch-file/) by [JakeBaldwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24465/jakebaldwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-10-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See $(env ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE) on http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args

You can use $(env HOME)

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2015-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5